# Laravel 4 Schema builder unsigned and a default value

Tags: laravel-4, schema

I'm using Laravel 4 schema builder and trying to create a field 'active' which is an int with a size of 1 and is unsigned but also has a default value of 0. I have tried the following code:

```
$table->int('active', 1)->default(0)->unsigned();
```

without success please could someone advise me on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're actually looking for is

```
$table->boolean('active')->default(false);
```

You could also represent it with

```
$table->tinyInteger('active')->default(0);
```

For a full list of options you should just have a [look ath the documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/schema).